# How to make custom prompt take effect at iex start?

Tags: elixir, elixir-iex

I have a custom prompt but when I launch `iex`, a builtin prompt shows. *After* I hit enter my prompt takes effect.  How can I make my prompt take effect when `iex` starts?

Here's what I'm seeing:

[image]

And this is my `.iex.exs` file:

```
IEx.configure(
  colors: [ enabled: true],
  default_prompt: [
      "\e[G",   # move to column 1
      "\e[35m", # magenta
      "MY %prefix(%counter)",
      ">",
      "\e[0m"   # reset
    ] |> IO.chardata_to_string
)
```

Comment: I guess it's a bug. What version of `iex` do you have?

Comment: 1.3.0 (as shown in the screenshot) this behavior existed in previous versions too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bug in `iex`. I've tracked down and fixed it: https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/pull/4895

Comment: Thanks so much for finding and fixing the bug.  And thanks to @JoséValim for reviewing and accepting your PR so quickly!