# Update elixir to include bug fixes?

Tags: elixir, elixir-iex

I'm relatively new to programming, however I have a little project I'm working on in elixir and in said project I want IEx to have a custom prompt. I am able to do so but as many of you may be aware there is a bug with this where the custom prompt only takes affect after you've asked IEx to return something. I'm aware there exists a fix and here is a link to the question that has that info: [How to make custom prompt take effect at iex start?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37974476/how-to-make-custom-prompt-take-effect-at-iex-start). However I cannot figure out how to update elixir to include this bug fix.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You can take the [tour] first and learn [ask] a good question and create a [mcve].  That makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: Which platform are you on Jake?  We can't tell you how to upgrade Elixir without knowing which platform you're on.

Comment: Sorry, its on a mac

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this web page: http://elixir-lang.org/install.html.

As you can see on the page there are several ways to install Elixir.  You don't need to "upgrade" so much as you need to simply install a newer version of Elixir.  Find your OS in the list and follow the instructions for it.  If you're building Elixir from source follow the instructions for that.

The process for upgrading Elixir is basically either install the new version or pull the latest source and rebuild.  Either way, that page should tell you what you need to know.