# Why does my iex.exs prompt configuration not happen until after I interact with Interactive Elixir

Tags: elixir

My ~/.iex.exs file only contains:

```
IEx.configure(default_prompt: "%prefix(%counter)*")
```

When I run iex I get:

```
$ iex
Erlang/OTP 19 [erts-8.0.2] [source] [64-bit] [smp:8:8] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false] [dtrace]

Interactive Elixir (1.3.2) - press Ctrl+C to exit (type h() ENTER for help)
iex(1)> IO.puts "where is my change?"
where is my change?
:ok
iex(2)*
```

My prompt changing to '*' does not happen until I interact with the shell. If I have

```
IO.puts "hello"
```

in my .iex then it will print "hello" when I start it. If I follow the example and have

```
IEx.configure(inspect: [limit: 3])
```

Then I get the expected results of

```
iex(1)> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[1,2,3,...]
```

I get this unexpected behavior in both terminal and iTerm2.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37974476/how-to-make-custom-prompt-take-effect-at-iex-start?

Comment: This patch will be in 1.4 so I am experiencing the same bug.